# TypeError: arrayBanner.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, redux

Tengo el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe por que sucede este error y como lo puedo solucionar al momento de crear un banner este se crea correctamente pero sale el error de arriba este es mi código:

```
export const createNewBanner = (Bdata,token) =>{
    return async (dispatch) =>{
        try {
            const formData = new FormData(); 
            let response = null
            formData.append("img", Bdata.img,  Bdata.img.name);
            formData.append("name", Bdata.name);
            formData.append("banner_id", Bdata.banner_id);
            formData.append("url", Bdata.url);
    
            response = await axios.post(`${urlBanner}/createnewbanner`, formData ,{headers:{"x-access-token":token , 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
            .then((data) =>{
                dispatch({
                    type: CREATE_BANNER,
                    payload: data.data,
                });
            })
            AlertSwalConfirm('top','Banner Creado Exitosamente','¡El banner se a creado correctamente!')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Esto es un error" + error)
            AlertSwalError('top','Error al crear banner','¡No se pudo crear el Banner!')
        }
    
    }
}
```

esta es la forma en como recorro mis datos que los traigo del state

```
for(let i=0; i< banner.length; i++){
        var arrayBanner = banner[0];
    }
```

este es mi map se encarga de colocar los datos dentro de una tabla

```
{arrayBanner?.map((value)=>{
      return <tr key={value._id}>
                <td className="td-namesub"><p className="t-td-namesub" key="{value}">{value.banner_id}</p></td>
                <td className="td-patnamesub"><p className="t-td-patnamesub" key="{value}">{value.name}</p></td>
                <td><img className="imgbanner" src={`data:image/png;base64,${btoa(new Uint8Array(value.img.data.data).reduce(function (data, byte) {return data + String.fromCharCode(byte);}, ''))}`} /></td>      
                 <td>
                    <Button type="button" className="btn-edit-banner" variant="outline-info" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Editar</Button>
                    <Button type="button" className="btn-eliminar-banner" variant="outline-danger" onClick={(e)=> deleteBanner(value._id)} data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Eliminar</Button>
                 </td>
              </tr>
})}
```

Comment: Podrías logear `arrayBanner` para ver que valor tiene?

Comment: @AndresGardiol Este es el arryaBanner[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Por favor copia y pega tal cual se logea en consola. Todo apunta a que `arrayBanner` no es un arreglo y por ende `.map` no es una funcion válida

Comment: @AndresGardiol no eso es lo que muestra el log de google Este es el arryaBanner[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el código del componente. Y si te es posible, una captura del log por consola cuando hagas `console.log(arrayBanner)`. Gracias